# Python subprocess - attempting to use a powershell script, but whitespaces in filepath cause errors

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, whitespace

**Background**: Trying to monitor something in Windows which is trivial to do in Powershell but a massive pain in Python. I would like to call a Powershell script from Python, have it print 'True' or 'False' to stdout, capture said output in Python, and continue on with the Python program.

**The Problem**: There are whitespaces in the path to the Powershell file. I have googled and tried every combination of double quotes, single quotes, backslashes and front slashes I can think of, but Powershell keeps throwing an error when the string is passed to it.

**What does work**: If I start the program from a location where I can run it with a whitespace-free relative path, everything works fine:

`result = subprocess.run(['powershell', "Python\CheckProcess\processCheck.ps1", "processName"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

**Examples of what does not work**:

Trying the following:

`result = subprocess.run(['powershell', "C:\\Path with spaces\\Python\\CheckProcess\\processCheck.ps1", "processName"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

`result = subprocess.run(['powershell', r"C:\Path with spaces\Python\CheckProcess\processCheck.ps1", "processName"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

`result = subprocess.run(['powershell', "C:\Path\ with\ spaces\Python\CheckProcess\processCheck.ps1", "processName"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

results in variations of: "The term 'C:\\Path' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or \noperable program"

Trying the following:

`result = subprocess.run(['powershell', "C:\Path with spaces\Python\CheckProcess\processCheck.ps1", "processName"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Results in: "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes"

And finally the following:

`result = subprocess.run(['powershell', "'C:\\Path with spaces\\Python\\CheckProcess\\processCheck.ps1'", "processName"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

`result = subprocess.run(['powershell', '"C:\\Path with spaces\\Python\\CheckProcess\\processCheck.ps1"', "processName"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

`result = subprocess.run(['powershell', '"""C:\\Path with spaces\\Python\\CheckProcess\\processCheck.ps1"""', "processName"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Return the message: Unexpected token 'processName' in expression or statement

**Powershell or Python?**

At least part of the problem seems to be that Python likes to create strings with doubled up backslashes (e.g. "C:\\Some Folder\\Another Folder") and Powershell cannot handle that in a filepath. I've experimented with the Pathlib module, but it just creates strings similar to the ones above resulting in the same error messages. Really stumped on how to get these languages to play well together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put "r" before the string with the filename. And you can use just one "\".

```
r"C:\Path with spaces\Python\CheckProcess\processCheck.ps1"
```

Comment: Tried, but I got the error: 

"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes".

I tried moving the file (in reality the file is being stored in a "C:\User\..." location, and I thought maybe the "\U" was causing problems). In its new location I got a different error: 

"rC:\Temp\Spaces Check\processCheck.ps1 : The term 'rC:\Temp\Spaces Check\checkIfFileCorrupt.ps1' is not recognized as the name..." 

so it looks like it is folding the 'r' into the string.

Comment: The `r` should be outside of the string, as in `r"C:\Path with spaces\"`.

Comment: @TripleD, there should not be double quoted string in the path name. I have updated the  answer. And r should come before the quotes as rightly noted by Ronald Smith

Comment: Thank you for the update. Unfortunately that does not work. As noted in the second example of my original post, it results in an error message indicating the parser is breaking at the white space.

Comment: @TripleD, on windows10, using python 3.10. This line works for me. And it has spaces . 
 subprocess.run([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice.exe"

Comment: @LetzerWille you lead me to the solution, but it was bizarre. I noticed that your answer was giving the full path to the exe. I replaced "powershell" with r"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" in my examples above and suddenly the string r"C:\Path with spaces\Python\CheckProcess\processCheck.ps1" worked just fine. Apparently subprocess doesn't like mixing raw and non-raw strings.